# mysqldump command not recognized when called from c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, command

I want to dump a mysql database through my c# app.
This is how the code looks like :

```
                ProcessStartInfo cmd = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                Arguments = "/C cd %programfiles%\\mysql\\mysql server 5.6\\bin\\ & mysqldump.exe --user=user --password=pwd --host=localhost --protocol=tcp --verbose=true --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-triggers \"db\" > \"mydb.sql\"",
                UseShellExecute = false,
            };
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(cmd))
            {
                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
```

But it says that "mysqldump" is not recognized as an internal command.
Note that when i execute the command in a normal command prompt windows, everything works fine.

I tried to put change the command llke this :

```
"/C cd /D %programfiles%\\mysql\\mysql server 5.6\\bin\\ & mysqldump.exe --user=user --password=pwd --host=localhost --protocol=tcp --verbose=true --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-triggers \"db\" > \"mydb.sql\""
```

But the execution seems to freeze my app for a way too long time.

Comment: a) Why are you running `cmd.exe` which _then_ runs the program rather than just running `mysqldump.exe` directly? b) Why does your command path have a space and `&` in it?

Comment: @gunr2171 a) how can i do that? b) since the mysql bin dir is not in the PATH, i have to navigate to the dir where mysqldump is stored, then execute it.

Comment: A bit too late, but i finally found a workaround. I removed the line UseShellExecute = false, and it worked like a charm